# convert string to float with precision of 2 (25.00) in C++

Tags: c++

In my assignment I have to take the string valve and convert it into float
for example

100 will be 100.00

100.0112 will be invalid

100.99 will stay as it is

99 will be 99.00

I'm thinking of using "stof" but I'm stuck on how to set the precision of 2.

Comment: By "float", do you specifically mean the C++ type `float` or just any (decimal?) fraction representation in general?

Comment: @sam If `100.00112` is invalid, what number is this converted to so as to make this valid?

Comment: @sam Then before you convert it to float, you need to take the string and discover if the user inputted more than 2 values after the decimal point.  You don't want to get into the weeds of first converting to float, and then try to determine if the float has two decimal digits.  Floating point is not exact, and once you convert the number to floating point, you're basically stuck with that number.

Comment: Sorry, I'm puzzled:  a float with value 99 has the same value than 99.0, or 99.00 or 99.00000... Do you have also to output the number with a precision of 2.  ?

Comment: Atually, I think that such a requirement is actually given to you as a *simplification* of the general problem of parsing a decimal number.

Comment: @sam I understand, but `float a=99f,b=99.00f,c=99.0000f; cout << a <<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<endl;` will print three times the same number.

Answer (score 1):

## Input validation

To check whether an input is valid or not, you might want to simply match it against a regular expression like

- `^([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` (if you don't allow leading zeros, except numbers strictly between -1.0 and 1.0) or
- `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` (if you do allow leading zeros) or
- `^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$` (if you allow to write `0.31` as just `.31` and allow leading zeros).

## Numbers for calculation

If you have to do any computation on the numbers encoded in the string, and if there isn't a hard requirement to use C++ type `float` consider using a fixed point type. Binary floating point types (even `double`) cannot exactly represent many decimal fractions (even when the latter are limited to two decimal places after the point).

## Numbers for text output

If you simply need to display/print the numbers encoded in the strings in the format with two decimal places, you have several options:

- After passed validation, convert the strings to a floating point format, e.g. with `stof` or `stod`. Then simply [output it with the wanted precision](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html). The precision of `double` should usually suffice to get back the original decimal value if the numbers aren't to large.

  or
- After passed validation, convert the strings to a fixed point format, and output that.

  or
- Never actually convert to numbers, instead produce the wanted output by string manipulation. Depending on how you do this, it might also take care of the validation. If it doesn't, only do this after passed validation as above.